# Deciding which document cluster a new document belong to

Tags: python-2.7, nltk, gensim

I am not expert in NLP related models. So I may be missing a simple point here. So please bear with me.

I have obtained topics and the corresponding keywords for each of those topic. I want to first cluster the documents based on these topics. That is, I want to see which document belongs to which topic. Next, given a new document, I need to find out which document clusters it belongs to. 
How do I do it ?

I think we need to pass the new document through the LDA model used to obtain the topics and then use the generated topics to measure its similarity with the previously obtained topics. However, I am not sure if this will work. For example, if the new document is a short document I don't know if it will work.

Any help will be extremely useful.

Thank you.

BTW: I am using Python 2.7 and the gensim package for the LDA algorithm